# How to delete an element while in list_for_each_entry_rcu

Tags: linux-kernel

1. I am using list_for_each_entry_rcu and inside the loop I want to delete an element from the list. How can I do that if there is no list_for_each_entry_rcu_safe?
2. I saw that in the past there was a macro list_for_each_safe_rcu. Why was it removed? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the view of RCU lists, all threads are divided into 2 groups:

- readers
- modifiers

At a time, the list could be accessed by **several readers** and a **single modifier**.

*Readers* should use `_rcu` primitives for list traversal.

In case of several *modifiers*, their access should be protected by a lock or other synchronization means.

So having `list_for_each_safe_rcu` is useless:

1. If your thread is a *modifier*, no other thread may modify a list at the same time. So, `_rcu` protection isn't needed and modifier may use `list_for_each_safe` for list traversal.
2. If your thread is a *reader*, it shouldn't modify a list, so it may use `list_for_each_rcu`.

---

Accessing a RCU list by two concurrent *modifiers* is generally **unsafe**. E.g., concurrent `list_del_rcu` on adjusted elements may corrupt a list.

Not sure why `list_for_each_safe_rcu` has been existed in the kernel 2.6.25 and before. In any case, it [hasn't been used anywhere](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.25.20/ident/list_for_each_safe_rcu).

Comment: Another question. Is it allowed to do a few list_del_rcu before synchronize_rcu?

Comment: `synchronize_rcu` is just a waitung before deleting recicling (freeing) RCU-resources. Of cource, you may wait once before freeing several elements list's elements.

Comment: Is it safe to call printk inside list_for_each_entry_rcu? Is there another way to print while in list_for_each_entry_rcu?

Comment: Yes, you may use `printk` while iterating list with `list_for_each_entry_rcu`.